# clearInterval() only works when time in setInterval() is constant

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

This function

```
const catchingEggs = () => { 
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        //if(speed >= 25) speed = 500 - score*15;
        if(eggBrokenLeft.style.visibility === "visible" || eggBrokenRight.style.visibility === "visible") {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            return
        }
        fallingEggs(allEggs[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)], speed);
        }, speed*3);     
}
```

works fine, as long as the second parameter of setInterval() doesn't change (for example `speed*3`, but if i uncomment `if(speed >= 25) speed = 500 - score*15;` it will only work if i lose within the first 3 intervals (until score reach 3), but if i keep playing and lose later (that's `eggBrokenLeft.style.visibility === "visible" || eggBrokenRight.style.visibility === "visible"`, part which should trigger clearInterval), nothing happens, the game just keeps playing.

I want to be able to increase the speed, WHILE in the interval and still be able to stop that interval. I guess I could write different intervals for different speeds and somehow put them together, but it would be messy, plus I want to be able to increase speed *gradually*, depending on the score.

Comment: The time between intervals is set on the initial call, updating the variable that was originally passed in won't affect the interval that was already created. To achieve that will probably need to create your own loop using a self-calling timeout (rather than interval)

Comment: it actually does affect it, when i uncomment that line, so the variable(speed), keeps updating, the function executes faster and faster, as expected. The issue is that clearInterval() won't work anymore.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, it sounds like perhaps multiple intervals are being added and it's giving the illusion of acceleration (which would also explain the clearing failing, as the reference you are storing in the variable only points at the most recent interval) Try putting a `console.log("test")` as the first line in the `catchingEggs` function and check it's only called once, if it appears multiple times, you're stacking up multiple looping intervals.

Comment: just tried, added `window.alert('test')` and it pops only once. i also know that the speed actually changes, because i added it to the screen, so i can track it. also, when before my setInterval() DID fire up multiple times for some error that i can't even remember, it looked completely different, there were multiple eggs on the screen, with same speed. Now, it's one egg at a time, with increasing gradually speed, as i had in mind. Maybe the fact that `fallingEggs(allEggs[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)], speed)` is composed of two `setTimeout()`'s has something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to implement an accelerating loop might be to use recursion on a function that executes commands within a `setTimeout` block. `setTimeout` has the advantage in this situation as it only executes once each time it is called and so intervals can be adjusted for each loop.

A conditional check within the timeout function determines whether to repeat the cycle, by making a call to the parent function, or whether to end repetition, by doing nothing. The interval applied to the timeout can be modified each time the function is executed.

This snippet demonstrates the principle by repeating a console log with increasing frequency until a specified minimum interval value is reached.

```js
let speed = 1000;
run();

function run() {

 setTimeout(function(){
 console.log(speed);
   if (speed > 200) {run()}; // repeat only if condition met;

  },speed-=50); // end timeout block;

}; // end function;
```

You might be able to apply your logic to this framework to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: so i did this `const run = () => {
    setTimeout(function(){
        //window.alert('test');
        fallingEggs(allEggs[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)], speed);
        if(stopped === false) run();
        else stopped = false ;         
    }, speed -=20)    
}` and it just executes itself multiple times simultaneously, doesn't wait for time interval.

Comment: Where is `stopped` set `true`? Have you checked it is ever `true`? And why would you ever need to set it `false` inside that block?

Comment: If there is no delay, even on the first run, you have probably not set speed, or it is a negative value.

Comment: it's set to `true` inside `fallingEggs`, when player fails to catch egg. then it is set to `false` again in above snippet, so another round of `fallingEggs()` can start. there is delay on the first run.